# Помогите разобраться с callback функциями

Tags: javascript, callback

Только вникаю в js и дошел до callback функций. Везде приводится такой пример.

```
function first(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("1"); }, 1000);
    callback();
}

function second() {
    console.log('2');
}



first(function () {
    second()
});
```

Но я не понимаю зачем передавать функцию second в качестве аргумента callback функции first если функцию second я могу и так вызвать без использования параметра.

```
function first() {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("1"); }, 1000);
    second();
}

function second() {
    console.log('2');
}




first();
```

Comment: затем, что не меняя функцию `first` в разных случаях ты можешь вызвать `second`, `third` и любую другую, даже анонимную. С твоим подходом тебе нужно будет либо копировать `first`, либо менять `second`, плюс переносить это все в один файл.

Comment: К тому же, мне кажется, у вас не совсем верный пример. Колбеки в большинстве случаев используются для обработки асинхронного кода. В вашем случае `callback` надо вызывать внутри `setTimeout`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не обязательно, простые примеры - методы массива типа map, filter и т.д. это вполне себе синхронные методы принимающие callback

Comment: @Grundy я и не спорю. Но в данном контексте колбек больше нужен для асинхронности, мне кажется.

Comment: На таких простых примерах трудно понять всю прелесть) Когда вы знаете, какую функцию нужно вызывать и где - ваш пример действительно уместнее, и проще, чем использование callback. Оно нужно для организации более сложных конструкций, когда вы заранее не знаете, какая функция прилетит и откуда. Частный пример: В играх, включая какой-нибудь эффект/усиление, функция-включатель может проверять, есть ли у эффекта дополнительные функции, которые нужно вызвать при включении. А различные функции для вызова, хранить в объектах самих эффектов.

Answer (score 2):

Коллбеки это вариант привязаться к определенной точке выполнения. Предположим Вы хотите что бы `childFunc()` начала выполняться только после того как функция `parentFunc()` будет завершена:

```
function parentFunc(callback) {
    // ... какой-либо синхронный код
    callback()
}

function childFunc() {
    console.log("Следующая фунция")
}

parentFunc(childFunc)
```

Или для асинхронного кода это возможность начать выполнения следующей функции только после того как асинхронная операция будет завершена:

```
function parentFunc() {
    setTimeout(childFunc, 1000)
}

function childFunc() {
    console.log("Следующая фунция")
}
```

В JavaScript на системе коллбеков основано многое, например [промисы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) это не что иное как те же самые коллбеки, только в более удобном виде.